# Disabling/removing the Team Foundation addin/extension in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have an older laptop that I won't get around to replacing for another month or two. It has 1GB of memory so I'm trying to squeeze applications as much as possible.

In Visual Studio 2010, it has apparently loaded some extensions related to Team Foundation Server, since I have menu items and dialog choices for it.

Questions:

1. Would I save a noticable amount of memory (even a couple of MB would be good) if I managed to disable this?
2. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Team Explorer is baked into VS 2010 and cannot be disabled.